# What is regular expression to replace up and until

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace

```
clientAddress=meat,London , lXV 546,United Kingdom, bankAddress=25,
```

with

```
clientAddress=maskedAddress, bankAddress=25,
```

I tried from string library:

```
replaceAll("clientAddress=[^\\, bankAddress]*", "clientAddress=maskedAddress, bankAddress"));
```

However this does not work?

Comment: just search for `bankAdress` and assemble the result using its value and skipping everything else

Comment: [`s.replace("(clientAddress=).*?(,\\s+bankAddress=\\d+)", "$1maskedAddress$2")`](https://regex101.com/r/AKCaqr/1)

Comment: @Zabuza You would have said *What do you think a character class means?*

Answer (score 1):

```
String address="clientAddress=meat,London , lXV 546,United Kingdom, bankAddress=25,";

address=address.replaceAll("(clientAddress=)(.+)(, bankAddress)", "clientAddress=maskedAddress, bankAddress");
System.out.println(address);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use that one?

```
public static void main(String[] ars) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, IOException, BadPaddingException {


     String test="clientAddress=meat,London , lXV 546,United Kingdom, bankAddress=25,";
     String replaced=test.replaceAll("(.*clientAddress=)(.+)(, bankAddress.+)", "$1maskedADdress$3");
     System.out.println(replaced);

}
```

Comment: Avoid asking questions in answers. Answers are meant to fully solve the issue, without the need of further discussion.

Answer (score -1):

You could use

```
String s = "clientAddress=meat,London , lXV 546,United Kingdom, bankAddress=25,";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(clientAddress=)(.*?)(, bankAddress=.*?)", "$1maskAddress$3"));
```

Comment: `(.*?)` and `$4` can be safely removed since `(.*?)` at the end of the pattern will always match an empty string.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew for pointing that out. I have updated the answer